# How to avoid password change when boot GRUB in debian 10 system?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, boot, grub, grub2

Per [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword),I know it's easy to change password when boot GRUB.
When I read [set debian grub password](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/lilo-passwd.en.html) ,I run command as below:

```
cat << EOF >> /boot/grub/menu.lst
timeout 3
password hackme
EOF
```

But it doesn't work,I can still change password when boot GRUB,without input `hackme`.
How to avoid password change when boot GRUB in debian 10 system?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords)? (recommend careful reading, easy to end up with inaccessible system)

Comment: @anx,then what 's usage of my script?password to protect what?